# how to open widget, have it do something, and close by itself?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to do the following:

I have a QMainWindow object. From it, I want to open window, have it do something, and close by itself.

Like start something > open window with "Loading.." message > do the thing > have the window close by itself without interaction from the user.

I have tried to create a QWidget class and put the "do the thing" method in there, but when I call the .show() method on the QWidget, the whole application hangs and doesn't go further, but maybe I don't understand the logic behind it.

I am using Python 3.7.7, PyQT5, my OS is Windows 10 x64 (if it's important)

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that I understood your question correctly. I would solve the problem in the following way:

```
from PyQt5 import QtTest
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QWidget

import sys


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.loading_window = None
        self.button = QPushButton("Push for Window")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.show_new_window)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.button)
        self.timer = QTimer()

    def show_new_window(self):
        if self.loading_window is None:
            self.loading_window = LoadingWindow()
        self.loading_window.show()
        self.do_your_job()
        self.close_loading_window()

    def do_your_job(self):
        # Do whatever you want here
        QtTest.QTest.qWait(1500)

    def close_loading_window(self):
        self.loading_window = None


class LoadingWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.label = QLabel('Loading')
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: yes, that was exactly what I wanted to do, thank you very much.
so the flow is - window.show() > do_stuff() in caller class > dereference window

thank you